# MySql: Joining two simple tables

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have two tables in my MySql database:

```
table #1: follows

  follower  |  following
 ------------------------
  john      |  dan
 ------------------------
  peter     |  john
 ------------------------
  peter     |  dan
 ------------------------
  john      |  peter
 ------------------------
  dan       |  peter
 ------------------------

 table #2: questions

  text           |  username
 ----------------------------
  something      |  peter
 ----------------------------
  something1     |  dan
 ----------------------------
  something2     |  peter
 ----------------------------
  something3     |  john
```

Let's say that I am logged in to the site with the username "dan".

I would like to see the most recent questions started by the people I follow. In this case, only questions from "peter".

The "follows" table contains every recorded follow made by someone and the "questions" table contains all questions.

I know MySql basics but I don't know anything about MySql JOIN. (<- I think I need JOIN to achieve my goal.)

My question: So how could I do this in a PHP script?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT q.username, q.text
    FROM follows f
        INNER JOIN questions q
            ON f.following = q.username
    WHERE f.follower = 'dan'
```

Comment: Ahh... thanks Joe! It is working! ;) I would like to have question though: How does it work? I am quite a beginner in MySql JOIN so if I would like to modiy the script later I wouldn't know how to do it! So could you give a brief explanation about what is what in it? Thanks... :)

Answer (score 1):

It's more efficient to do your record filtering on the database rather than dumping all your records down and doing it inside of your PHP script.  Your query could be accomplished either with a JOIN:

```
SELECT q.* 
FROM questions q 
JOIN follows f ON f.following = q.username 
WHERE f.follower = 'dan'
```

or by subquery

```
SELECT q.* 
FROM questions q 
WHERE q.username IN ( SELECT f.following
                      FROM follows f
                      WHERE f.follower = 'dan' )
```

(Outside the scope of your question, but you may want to add some type of unique index to your tables, so going forward if you want to remove a specific question or perhaps get rid of a person you're following, you can do so by deletion on the index rather than having to specify a combination of fields to get to your unique record.)

Answer (score 0):

-- inner join with USING clause
SELECT *
FROM  a INNER JOIN  b
USING()

-- inner join with ON clause
SELECT *
FROM  a INNER JOIN  b
ON a. = b.

Try in this way :)